# Why multiple azure pipelines are being triggered although I am triggering only once?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a source pipeline kvi_test which is triggering the HYBM_Pipelines_Rebuild on its completion. The pipeline in HYBM_Pipelines_Rebuild is

```
trigger: none


resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: ArtifactsPipeline
    source: kvi_test  # Name of the pipeline generating artifacts
    trigger: true

   #pipeline steps...
```

When the kvi_test pipeline is completed
[HYBM_Pipelines_Rebuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeDr4.png) is being triggered multiple times why?

Comment: maybe you're running into WordPressParsePoJob ?

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot that you have shared, I am pretty sure that you have created several **pipelines**, which all include the same pipeline resource `kvi_test` and are all defined to be triggered by the completion of each succeeded build of `kvi_test`.

[image]

Given the naming pattern, your repo name should be `HYBM_Pipelines_Rebuild` and all the pipelines `HYBM_Pipelines_Rebuild` `(1) - (8)` are probably using the same `.yml` file from this repo with the pipeline resource of `kvi_test` in its YAML definition.

Therefore, they are **multiple pipelines** with similar names, which are triggered by the same resource, **rather than multiple builds of one single pipeline** that gets triggered multiple times. Since this behavior may be unexpected, please remove additional pipelines if you believe it is unnecessary to use them.